# Chain of connected points and rotation matrices

Tags: math, geometry, matrix, rotation

Thanks for looking at this. I apologize for this rather lengthy build-up but I thought it is needed to clarify things.

I have a chain of connected atoms, say a polymer which has rigid bonds and bond angles. With rigid bonds we get the condition that the distance between two immediate neighbours [eg. 2-3,3-4,etc.] is always fixed and the bond angles [defined using 3 atoms, eg. 1-2-3] are always maintained. We do have freedom to rotate around the torsion angles. The atoms are defined with respect to each previous atom by this length, angle and the torsion angle and that basically allows us to find the Cartesian coordinates by setting up a coordinate system. Now, if we want to align a pair of atoms which are not directly connected to the base atoms with respect to which the new orientations are supplied can we find a rotation matrix that can do the job?

For example, imagine that we have 10 atoms and we want to define a new set of internal coordinates between atoms 1,2 and 9,10. The locations in space of atoms 9 and 10 have been found using the internal coordinates specified by atoms 6, 7 and 8. [Distance 8-9, angle 7-8-9 and the torsion angle 6-7-8-9 and similarly for atom 10]

Now if we decide to reorient atoms 9 and 10 by defining a distance as 2-9 and the angle 1-2-9 and the dihedral angle 1-2-9-10, is there a way to find a rotation/transformation matrix that will perform this realignment without disturbing the geometry of the rest of the atoms [that is it will preserve the angle 7-8-9, distance 8-9 and dihedral 6-7-8-9].

Thanks a lot in advance for any advice.

Comment: This reminds me of inverse kinematics (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_kinematics), but I'm not sure if that will help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is *really* unclear. Are you saying that you start with all distances, angles and dihedral angles {n-(n+1), n-(n+1)-(n+2), n-(n+1)-(n+2)-(n+3)}, and you want to calculate {2-9, 1-2-9, 1-2-9-10}?

Comment: @Beta: I am saying that when we begin, we know all distances and angles, but then we want to change the distance,angles between non- immediate neighbour connections like [2-9,1-2-9, 1-2-9-10] and the question is that is there a way to do it while preserving (fixed) the immediate neighbour connections around atoms 9 and 10 [and all other atoms in fact]. Thanks for considering the question.

Comment: @Andy: Thanks Andy. I think that is the area where such questions are concerned; however as you said I'm not sure if there is some prescription or well-defined approach to answer this question.

Comment: Do you want to change the configuration of the molecule in a way that changes the distance 2-9, but leaves the distances 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5, 5-6, 6-7, 8-9, 9-10 and the angles 1-2-3, 2-3-4, 3-4-5, 4-5-6, 5-6-7, 6-7-8, 7-8-9, 8-9-10 and the dihedral angles 1-2-3-4, 2-3-4-5, 3-4-5-6, 4-5-6-7, 5-6-7-8, 6-7-8-9, 7-8-9-10 fixed? That is not possible.

Comment: @Jitse: Thanks for the comment. We don't need to preserve the dihedrals, but we must preserve the bond lengths and bond angles. That's why I have a hunch that there must be a Transformation matrix which can do it.

Comment: Andy is right, this is exactly inverse kinematics.  Just like a robot arm, with the additional restriction that you can only mess with dihedral angles, not angles (typically robots can change angles).  It's a hard problem to solve, fortunately lots of people have looked at it so there's some software out there to do it.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm a bit confused, I will take a stab at it. It sounds like you have a set of points and want to reorient them while fixing some in certain locations and preserving the spatial relationships of the group. If you know the coordinates of 4 points in the starting location and their coordinates in the destination location, you can just put those points (x,y,z,1) as columns in a 4x4 matrix S. You put the destination coordinates in another matrix D. Then you solve D = MS where D is the destination, S is the source, and M will be the transformation that takes you from S to D. So we right-multiply by S~ (inverse) to get M = DS~.

On another note, I would recommend that you never use angles for this type of thing. If you want to make a constraint that the angle between atoms 4-5-6 is a certain value, a much better representation is to store the dot product d = (4-5)*(6-5). This of course assumes the distances are not variable and the 3 atom set is rigid.